# How can I run a sub function in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

How can I run a 'sub function' from a script in command line? Example:

```
#script_1.sh
main_function() {
    sub_function() {
         echo "hello world"
    }
}
```

I tried to source this file and call the function from another script:

```
#script_2.sh
source script_1.sh

sub_function
```

But I get

```
script_2.sh: line 3: sub_function: command not found
```

while I expected to just get `hello world`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thus defined the `sub_function` will be defined after `function` is called.
So:

```
#script_1.sh
function() {
    sub_function() {
         #cmd
        }
}

#script_2.sh
source script_1.sh
function
sub_function
```

... should work ... except you should rename function, as it's a reserved word

Comment: `function` is a keyword so you need to pick a name but otherwise, yes.

Comment: But I guess this will also execute "function" which might do other things, I ONLY want to execute "sub_function". Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

The step missing in your question is to invoke `function` first - its action is to define `sub_function`.

Note that `sub_function` doesn't 'belong' to `function` in any way - its definition is just a side-effect of running `function`.

P.S. I assume you aren't really trying to call it `function` - that's a reserved word in bash.